# Rambam Interlinear Online?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, rambam, translation, english

Does anyone know a place online where I can find and English, interlinear translation of the Rambam?

The only English I found is [on the chabad.org website](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm).

But that is far from interlinear.

So where I can find it where **at least** the Hebrew and English are side by side?
Interlinear would be best, but any side by side will do.

I do not need the full Mishneh Torah I just need Hilchos Avodas Kochavim.

Edit: Danno gave me Hilchos Teshuva all on Sefaria but I still need Hilchos Avodas Kochavim. If Anyone know it will be very helpful thank you!

Comment: Hello user6781, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! You may want to change your name, unless you prefer the number 6781 :P. I don't known if there is an answer to your question, as I'm not certain that there are _any_ interlinear translations of the Rambam, even in print.

Comment: In print I know there is one in Moznaim, (not interlinear but much better). I saw the introduction of one. (On mechon mamre) But that was it. So maybe it does not exist but more than a few times I have been surprised.

Comment: I have been surprised by the Jewish resources available online too ;) .... Wait around, and see what answers come in.

Comment: theres one published by kfar habad i think. http://www.eichlers.com/mishnah-torah-l-harambam-rambam-ha-meir-vol-1-hilchos-yesodei-hatorah.html there were a bunch of free sample pdfs on a website but i cant find them now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechon Mamre has the [introduction](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/p0000.htm) translated interlinearly though not artscroll-style.

[Sefaria](http://sefaria.org) has a number of chapters (see [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Transmission_of_the_Oral_Law.1) for one) translated with the english side-by-side, mostly in Sefer HaMadda. Because the translation is crowd-sourced (though moderated for accuracy) that "number" may be larger by the time you click the link. (full disclosure: I like sefaria and translate things for them.)

Comment: Thank you so much! It has everything I needed. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. May I recommend that you contribute to sefaria by translating what you are able?